# R how to arrange diagnostic plots differently

Tags: r, diagnostics

I'm trying to figure out how I can arrange diagnostic plots differently using the plot() function. Here is my code:

```
mtcars_linear_model <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)

plot(mtcars_linear_model)
```

It will print these four plots in my console.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to arrange them using ggarrange? I can't seem to print one of them at a time. I thought maybe I could call the index with the plot() function to get the plots one at a time but it doesn't work:

```
plot(mtcars_linear_model)[1]
```

I want to use each plot separately in ggarrange like this:

```
ggarrange(residuals_vs_fitted, normal_qq, scale_location, residuals_vs_leverage)
```

So that I could get one image with a 2x2 grid of these four diagnostic plots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using R base

```
x11()
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(mtcars_linear_model)
```

This will produce:

[image]

You can reset plot params by `par(mfrow=c(1,1))`

Comment: I'm sort of having trouble understanding the x11() part of this. I'm using Google and it says something about windows operating system. I'm using a Mac. Does this Mac a difference? I've never seen x11() before

Comment: you can use [`quartz` to start a graphic window](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grDevices/versions/3.6.2/topics/quartz).